# How to create live word counter in AS3 text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm going to create an edit options in a flash input text fields: I need live word count.
How count the words that user is typing live?

Comment: RegEx is your friend. Match spaces not at the beginning or end of the string, get the length of the array, and add 1 (for the first word) to it. Easy enough.

Comment: Why add 1?  The length of the array is how many words there are.

Comment: @Ribs You're thinking of split, which might be the better route here (and why I upvoted your answer). With RegEx, we will count the spaces. This sentence has 9 words but only 8 spaces. So you have to add one to account for that difference.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now.  Thx for the upvote.  :)  I like the regex idea tho too.

Comment: What is the 'cut and paste' bit you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, where we count groups of non-whitespace characters:

```
function countWords(input:String):int
{
    // Match collections of non-whitespace characters.
    return input.match(/[^\s]+/g).length;
}
```

Some tests:

```
trace(countWords("")); // 0
trace(countWords("Simple test.")); // 2
trace(countWords("  This  is an  untrimmed string ")); // 5
```

Comment: I want count the words live. Each space key pressed update the word counts. I don't know how do this.

Comment: @Amir You have to attach an event listener to the TextField for when the content changes and use my function inside that.

Comment: If you mean 'myTextfield.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,countWords);' it does't work.

Comment: @Amir No you have to make a handler function and use countWords within that.

Comment: `myTextfield.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,count);
function count(e:Event):void{
trace(countWords(myTextfield.text));
function countWords(input:String):int
  {
    return input.match(/[^\s]+/g).length;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of words in a text field, split the string in the textfield by the spaces.  This will return an array of all the words in the textfield.  Get the length of the array to tell how many words were entered:

```
var words:Array = myTextFieldInput.split( ' ' ); 
var numberOfWords = words.length;
```

As for copying text from a textfield and pasting it into another, as long as the textfield is selectable, that behavior should be native to the operating system.

Comment: Be careful of spaces next to each other, line breaks, etc. Also your naming of `myTextField` is a little misleading because you can't `split` a TextField.

Comment: Thanks, but this count the white spaces as words.